# Fast rolling correlation using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the data.table below, I am trying to find a 7 days rolling Spearman correlation of the column `value` with the ideal trend line vector `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)` (with slope 1). The function `cor` is super slow when tested on larger tables (my actual data.table is much larger). Does anyone know any other function that can produce much faster results? `cor` function makes a local copy of data and that makes it too slower for large datasets.

```
temp_dt = structure(list(date = structure(c(18540L, 18541L, 18542L, 18543L, 
18544L, 18547L, 18548L, 18549L, 18550L, 18551L, 18554L, 18555L, 
18556L, 18557L, 18558L, 18561L, 18562L, 18563L, 18564L, 18565L, 
18568L, 18569L, 18570L, 18571L, 18572L, 18575L, 18576L, 18577L, 
18578L, 18579L, 18582L, 18583L, 18584L, 18585L, 18586L, 18589L, 
18590L, 18591L, 18593L, 18596L, 18597L, 18598L, 18599L, 18600L, 
18603L, 18604L, 18605L, 18606L, 18607L, 18610L, 18611L, 18612L, 
18613L, 18614L, 18617L, 18618L, 18619L, 18620L, 18624L, 18625L, 
18626L, 18627L, 18631L, 18632L, 18633L, 18634L, 18635L, 18638L, 
18639L, 18640L, 18641L, 18642L, 18646L, 18647L, 18648L, 18649L, 
18652L, 18653L, 18654L, 18655L, 18656L, 18659L, 18660L, 18661L, 
18662L, 18663L, 18666L, 18667L, 18668L, 18669L, 18670L, 18674L, 
18675L, 18676L, 18677L, 18680L, 18681L, 18682L, 18683L, 18684L
), class = c("IDate", "Date")), value = c(217.65, 211.45, 219.02, 
218.45, 218.95, 216.51, 212.07, 210.53, 213.93, 210.56, 203.42, 
200.85, 195.96, 200.55, 208.01, 200.26, 200.35, 195.03, 196.2, 
193.58, 192.58, 197.59, 198.47, 204.82, 200.8, 236.4, 233.48, 
221.51, 222.13, 225.41, 230.97, 225.02, 234.62, 233.09, 232.53, 
230, 225.95, 222, 221.58, 218.54, 220.58, 226.23, 229.25, 231.08, 
229.99, 233.34, 237.4, 233.1, 229.51, 230.51, 237.1, 234.49, 
245.16, 240.85, 240.77, 245.88, 249.93, 247.88, 258.32, 259.15, 
260.24, 261.55, 253.38, 252.24, 267.22, 264.09, 264.97, 263.88, 
262.69, 258.1, 253.06, 253.92, 252.06, 253.69, 253.98, 252.25, 
252.54, 251.32, 236.99, 250.09, 248.9, 248.33, 252.36, 252.72, 
256.9, 255.99, 263.85, 263.99, 259.79, 265.35, 262.66, 263.3, 
264.79, 264.85, 264.81, 264.64, 264.91, 269.63, 261.62, 258.82
)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

I have tried the following statement, which is producing slow results -

```
temp_dt[, corr := frollapply(x = value, n = 7, cor, fill = NA, align = "right", method = "spearman", y = 1:7)]
> tail(temp_dt)
 95: 2021-02-19 264.81  0.42857143
 96: 2021-02-22 264.64  0.00000000
 97: 2021-02-23 264.91  0.75000000
 98: 2021-02-24 269.63  0.75000000
 99: 2021-02-25 261.62  0.00000000
100: 2021-02-26 258.82 -0.42857143
```

Here is the speed

```
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    slower = temp_dt[, corr := frollapply(x = value, n = 7, cor, fill = NA, align = "right", method = "spearman", y = 1:7)],
    times = 5
  )


Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 slower 14.37227 14.39736 15.0515 15.01405 15.44279 16.03103     5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options. Creating a matrix with the rolling windows along the columns is the fastest for a relatively small rolling window.

```
library(Rfast)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cor = dt[, frollapply(x = value, n = 7, cor, fill = NA, align = "right", method = "spearman", y = 1:7)],
  manual = {sdr <- sd(r <- 1:7); dt[,frollapply(value, 7, \(x) cov(y <- rank(x), r)/sd(y)/sdr, fill = NA, align = "right")]},
  matrix1 = dt[, c(rep(NA_real_, 6), cor(matrix(value[sequence(rep(7, 94), 1:94)], 7), 1:7, method = "spearman"))],
  matrix2 = dt[, c(rep(NA_real_, 6), cor(colRanks(matrix(value[sequence(rep(7, 94), 1:94)], 7)), 1:7))],
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>      cor 2858.2 2978.35 3501.439 3111.85 3566.55 6869.4   100
#>   manual 2620.6 2727.85 3082.427 2783.50 2931.40 6492.3   100
#>  matrix1 1054.4 1113.10 1302.680 1153.60 1235.30 6125.3   100
#>  matrix2  238.6  267.90  313.512  280.85  304.70 1920.2   100
```

Comment: ```matrix2``` worked best. I modified it to ```matrix2 = dt[, c(rep(NA_real_, 6), cor(colRanks(matrix(value[sequence(rep(7, .N-6), 1:(.N-6))], 7)), 1:7))]``` to generalize the solution to work on all groups of data.table. Can there be a better generalization?

Comment: If the window length (7 here) could change, you could generalize on that. But otherwise, yes, what you posted will generalize for the `data.table`.

Comment: Hi @jblood. I want to find the rolling correlation between two columns ```value1``` and ```value2```. I am using the following code to find it but getting way more rows than I am supposed to get. Is there any problem with this code? ```matrix2 = dt[, c(rep(NA_real_, 6), cor(colRanks(matrix(value1[sequence(rep(7, .N-6), 1:(.N-6))], 7)), colRanks(matrix(value2[sequence(rep(7, .N-6), 1:(.N-6))], 7))))]```

Comment: I have created a new question for this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019260/fast-rolling-correlation-between-two-columns-of-data-table.

Comment: Use `Rfast::corpairs` instead of `cor`.