# Fast rolling correlation between two columns of data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

In the data.table below, I am trying to find a 7 days rolling Spearman correlation between the columns `value1` and `value2`.

```
temp_dt = structure(list(date = structure(c(19390L, 19391L, 19394L, 19395L, 
19396L, 19397L, 19398L, 19401L, 19402L, 19403L, 19404L, 19405L, 
19409L, 19410L, 19411L, 19412L, 19415L, 19416L, 19417L, 19418L, 
19419L, 19422L, 19423L, 19424L, 19425L, 19426L, 19429L, 19430L, 
19431L, 19432L, 19433L, 19436L, 19437L, 19438L, 19439L, 19440L, 
19443L, 19444L, 19445L, 19446L, 19447L, 19450L, 19451L, 19452L, 
19453L, 19457L, 19458L, 19459L, 19460L, 19461L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), close = c(21.34, 21.4, 21.45, 21.37, 21.26, 21.14, 
21.33, 21.28, 21.15, 21.03, 21.11, 21.22, 21.47, 21.38, 20.78, 
20.54, 20.24, 19.88, 19.87, 19.87, 20.08, 20.09, 20, 20.11, 19.93, 
19.91, 19.63, 19.64, 19.73, 19.68, 19.5, 19.2, 19.34, 19.65, 
19.9, 20.19, 20.31, 20.33, 20.32, 20.5, 20.78, 20.9, 20.75, 20.94, 
21.05, 21.21, 20.87, 20.64, 20.63, 20.69), bop_green = c(0.00302961, 
0.0231944, 0.0374391, 0.0390877, 0.03104, 0.0131761, 0.0131656, 
0.00135036, -0.0208444, -0.0470593, -0.0502583, -0.0391544, -0.013647, 
-0.0106879, -0.0103398, -0.027718, -0.0562916, -0.0885738, -0.101889, 
-0.117401, -0.115863, -0.118662, -0.123646, -0.114466, -0.126912, 
-0.13905, -0.158688, -0.17043, -0.165913, -0.165853, -0.165351, 
-0.181065, -0.181714, -0.160895, -0.126132, -0.0803255, -0.0442461, 
-0.0255004, -0.0293242, -0.0132638, 0.0143276, 0.0355189, 0.0398848, 
0.0508185, 0.054249, 0.0759373, 0.0894885, 0.0744317, 0.0643457, 
0.0695191)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

> head(temp_dt, 20)
          date value1     value2
 1: 2023-03-17  19.50 -0.1653510
 2: 2023-03-20  19.20 -0.1810650
 3: 2023-03-21  19.34 -0.1817140
 4: 2023-03-22  19.65 -0.1608950
 5: 2023-03-23  19.90 -0.1261320
 6: 2023-03-24  20.19 -0.0803255
 7: 2023-03-27  20.31 -0.0442461
 8: 2023-03-28  20.33 -0.0255004
 9: 2023-03-29  20.32 -0.0293242
10: 2023-03-30  20.50 -0.0132638
11: 2023-03-31  20.78  0.0143276
12: 2023-04-03  20.90  0.0355189
13: 2023-04-04  20.75  0.0398848
14: 2023-04-05  20.94  0.0508185
15: 2023-04-06  21.05  0.0542490
16: 2023-04-10  21.21  0.0759373
17: 2023-04-11  20.87  0.0894885
18: 2023-04-12  20.64  0.0744317
19: 2023-04-13  20.63  0.0643457
20: 2023-04-14  20.69  0.0695191
```

Since I want this operation to be as fast as possible, I am generalizing the code from the post - [Fast rolling correlation using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929969/fast-rolling-correlation-using-data-table)

The code I am trying to implement is following

```
library(data.table)
library(Rfast)
temp_dt[, c(rep(NA_real_, 6), cor(Rfast::colRanks(matrix(value1[sequence(rep(7, .N-6), 1:(.N-6))], 7)), Rfast::colRanks(matrix(value2[sequence(rep(7, .N-6), 1:(.N-6))], 7))))]
```

However, I am getting a vector with 443562 entries in return. The expected number of values in returned vector should be no more than 50. Any help on what I am doing wrong will be helpful. It must be a stupid mistake.

I have tried another alternative in the following code and it is also giving error - `Error in (function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson",  : incompatible dimensions`

```
temp_dt[, corr := frollapply(x = value1, n = 7, cor, fill = NA, align = "right", method = "spearman", y = value2)]
```

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to do? Using the first 8 rows, show how the result should look like. Whatever you are doing and what the link has is completely different

Comment: Are you aiming at obtaining the collelation between the two cols or within the two cols?

Comment: I am trying to find the rolling correlation between the two columns.

Comment: Then how is the expected length only 50? ie you have the for example in the first column, you will have 14 columns. In the second you will also have 14 columns each for both. That will bring around 196 values in total ie 14^2... so where are you getting the 50 from?

Comment: I have added the expected output. I am NOT trying to find the cross-correlation. I am trying to find the rolling 7-day correlation between the value1 and value2 columns.

Comment: And the result shows that you do not even need the spearman rank but you need the pearson thus you do not even need `Rfast`. Am I correct?

Comment: Try new frollapply: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/5575

Comment: @Onyambu, I have updated the example in question and it requires ```spearman``` correlation now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the correlation between pairs of variables (each corresponding column from the two matrices returned by `colRanks` is a pair of variables). Use `Rfast::corpairs`:

```
temp_dt[, c(rep(NA_real_, 6), corpairs(colRanks(matrix(value1[sequence(rep(7, .N-6), 1:(.N-6))], 7)), colRanks(matrix(value2[sequence(rep(7, .N-6), 1:(.N-6))], 7))))]
```